# Accessing environment variables set using mod_rewrite in PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have this little .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ urlroute.php?q=$1 [E=myvariable:'withthisvalue',B,QSA]
```

To direct all requests to my URL routing script. It works great and I can access the requested URL in urlroute.php as `$_GET['q']`.

I'm setting the environment variable `myvariable` using mod_rewrite 
I am able to access it in urlroute.php as `$_SERVER['myvariable']`. I am not able to access it using `$_ENV['myvariable']` which seems strange. Could someone please explain what the reason could be?

To my knowledge, mod_redirect will prepend `REDIRECT_` to environment variable names when doing a redirect (which it always does in my case). But for me both `$_SERVER['myvariable']` and `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_myvariable']` are available and set to the same content. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules) also discusses the same feature.  The rewrite engine loops on evaluating `.htaccess` files at the start of each cycle the engine copies any environment variables into a copy **REDIRECT_***.  Hence if the parsing of the `.htaccess` files requires 3 loops then you will also get **REDIRECT_REDIRECT_*** files, and so on.

Apache 2.3 includes a new `[E]` flag but you can used this feature to implement the same in earlier versions:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_END} =1
RewriteRule ^   -  [L]   

# other rules

...

RewriteRule somepattern  somesubst   [L,E=END:1]
```

AFAIK, these variables will available the **SERVER** context, but whether they are available in the **ENVIRONMENT** depends on how PHP is implemented e.g. Apache+mod_php, Apache+mod_suphp, Apache+mod_fcgi, IIS, ...

Comment: +1 for good answer, however I think you meant `RewriteCond` instead of `RedirectCond`.

Comment: @anubhava, that's what I call a "mindfart".  Sorry.  of course you are right.  I've edited the answer